# Hazelcast - Ignore Local Messages

Tags: messaging, hazelcast

For a specific use case I need to publish to an ITopic and also consume messages from the same ITopic with a Hazelcast client (not instance). I however do not wish to process the messages which is generated on the topic locally, i.e. the same component should not generate and consume its own message.

For JMS, there is a provision to ignore local messages. I however, do not find such an option for Hazelcast ITopic.

As a workaround I tried to compare, the Message.getMember().getUUID and HazelcastInstance.localEndpoint().getUUID(), to see if they are same. They are not same (somehow I did not expect them to be same as it is a client-server setup).

Now the question is, is there any mechanism in Hazelcast API that can be used to ignore local messages? Or do I have to fallback on maintaining a message tag based on the component/client and filter messages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `Topic` is to be distributed, and that any consumer can subscribe to events. Hence, there's no such thing as locality.

I'm afraid you'll need to add additional meta-data identifying your node in the message and set a filter based on it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `message.getPublishingMember().localMember()` as described [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/cluster/Member.html#localMember--)

This will return `true` if the message is sent by the local `HazelcastInstance` and otherwise `false`.

If it is `true`, just ignore the message. There is no need to introduce a message tag.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I shall check, sure